# php mysql display selected records from result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which fetches replies to comments.
so my first query has them comments,
e.g.

```
comment 1 <BR>
  &nbsp; reply 1<BR>
comment 2<BR>
comment 3<BR>
   &nbsp; reply 1<BR>
   &nbsp; reply 2<BR>
   &nbsp; reply 2<BR>
```

Comment 3 has 3 replies. I make one query to fetch all replies from my database where the `commentID`
in (1,2,3) . This will bring me all valid replies.

Now the problem is when I want to display the results, I start a `while` loop and go through all the comments.

How do I get the selected replies just for that particular comment while in the `while` loop?

Comment: Run another query in each while loop...?

Comment: That's what i initially used to do , but i was told to do it this way in another post , but i dont understand how to ....

Comment: do you remember the link to that post?

Comment: @victoroux check below -sorted out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you stored the replies in a multidimensional array lets say `$array_replies`, this is how youd do it

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($array_replies[$commentID]); $i++) {
   echo $array_replies[$commentID][$i];
}
```

Comment: my replies record set will return 4 rows, and if i was in the while loop at the point where i was displaying the replies for comment 3  , i would only like to dispaly 3 of the records from the result where they match the commentID